# In Dart, syntactically nice way to cast dynamic to given type or return null?

Tags: dart

I have a `dynamic x` and I would like to assign `x` to `T s` if `x is T`, and otherwise assign `null` to `s`. Specifically, I would like to avoid having to type `x` twice, and to avoid creating a temporary. (For example, I don't want to have to write `String s = map['key'] is String ? map['key'] : null;` over and over, because I will have many such expressions.) I don't want there to be any possibility of a runtime error.

The following works:

```
class Cast<T> {
  T f(x) {
    if (x is T) {
      return x;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

// ...

dynamic x = something();
String s = Cast<String>().f(x);
```

Is there a syntactically nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Dart 2 has generic functions which allows

```
T? cast<T>(x) => x is T ? x : null;
```

```
dynamic x = something();
String s = cast<String>(x);
```

you can also use

```
var /* or final */ s = cast<String>(x);
```

and get `String` inferred for `s`

Comment: You should also be able to do `String s = cast(x);` and get the type parameter to `cast` inferred from the context.

Comment: Does this function still exit? Because the IDE does not seem to have this

Comment: This seems still to be work in progress. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33075 might help.

Comment: where is this function defined ?

Comment: @LeresAldtai in my answer ;-) You need to define it yourself.

Comment: If you turn on null safety in dart. It'd be `T? cast<T>(x) => x is T ? x : null;`

Answer (score 21):

I use the following utility function, which allows for an optional fallback value and error logging.

```
T? tryCast<T>(dynamic x, {T? fallback}){
    try{
        return (x as T);
    }
    on CastError catch(e){
        print('CastError when trying to cast $x to $T!');
        return fallback;
    }
}
```

```
var x = something();
String s = tryCast(x, fallback: 'nothing');
```

Comment: How can that return `T` instead of `T?` if `fallback` is optional?  If `fallback` is omitted and `x is! T`, then won't it return a null?   

I'm guessing something has changed in dart over the years.

Comment: @Jobu Yes, the previous answer was written long before sound null-safety was a thing. I have edited it to be null safe.

Answer (score 15):

I'm using those with Dart null safety (Dart SDK >= 2.12):

```
T? castOrNull<T>(dynamic x) => x is T ? x : null;

T castOrFallback<T>(dynamic x, T fallback) => x is T ? x : fallback;
```

Comment: I just love these!

Answer (score 14):

Just use the **as** keyword

```
final tweet = tweets[index] as Tweet;
```

Comment: does this return null if the type not match?

Comment: `as` is a `forced type cast` and is not safe

Comment: This cannot be used anywhere. It does not return null if the type is not the given one. Instead, it throws an error. You should use it only if you're sure about the type.

Answer (score 9):

This hidden gem was [provided by one of Dart-Lang's maintainers](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/399#issuecomment-834258064):

```dart
extension AsExtension on Object? {
  X as<X>() => this as X;
  X? asOrNull<X>() {
    var self = this;
    return self is X ? self : null;
  }
}

extension AsSubtypeExtension<X> on X {
  Y asSubtype<Y extends X>() => this as Y;
}

extension AsNotNullExtension<X> on X? {
  X asNotNull() => this as X;
}

// example
void main() {
  num? n = 1 as dynamic;
  n.as<int>().isEven;
  n.asSubtype<int>().isEven; // `n.asSubtype<String>()` is an error.
  n.asNotNull().floor();
  n.asOrNull<int>()?.isEven; // Corresponds to `(n as? int)?.isEven`.
}
```

***NOTE***: If your object is of type `dynamic`, you have to cast it `Object?` first. The explanation for this can be found here: first one [by Erik, a dart maintainer @Google](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/399#issuecomment-933255132) and the second [by a community member](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/399#issuecomment-932844271). Basically it boils down to dart not calling extension methods on receives of one of the following three types: `dynamic`, `Never`, or `void` as stated [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/1696837c8010d1f9e9d21d8540e3535530306df3/specification/dartLangSpec.tex#L6204).

Comment: I like this answer, but I'd recommend changing the generic to `X extends Object?`. If you don't it's possible to coerce a `dynamic` type from this method. This can lead to runtime errors. For example: if you think you've coerce an `int`, and tried calling `toDouble()` on it. The analyzer won't complain, but it will throw an error when you run it.

Answer (score 7):

A combination of both prior two posts, without the logging.

Fallback defaults to null when not provided.

```
T cast<T>(dynamic x, {T fallback}) => x is T ? x : fallback;
```

Comment: It should be ```T? cast<T>(dynamic x, {T? fallback}) => x is T ? x : fallback;```

Answer (score 3):

> CastError is deprecated, Instead use TypeError.

With null safety, you can try the below snippet. Where fallback is optional/nullable.

```
T? tryCast<T>(dynamic value, {T? fallback}) {
  try {
    return (value as T);
  } on TypeError catch (_) {
    return fallback;
  }
}
```

Or without **fallback** -

```
T? tryCast<T>(dynamic value) {
  try {
    return (value as T);
  } on TypeError catch (_) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Usage** -

```
final val = tryCast<String>(1) ?? "";
```